# a[title]:hover:after doesn't display like it should (hidden by other div)

Tags: html, css

Here's my page http://giantgag.com/?p=6775
On the right side (depending on your screen resolution) there is posts, when you hover there is title displaying.

The title doesn't go over other posts

I tried setting z-index but no success

here's the css

```
.index_thumb a[title]:hover:after{
    content:attr(title);
    z-index:9999;
    height:100%;
    color:#000;
    font-size:20px;
    text-align:left;
    padding-left:10px;
    width:150px;
    background-color:rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6);
}
```

Comment: Read up on [stacking context.](http://philipwalton.com/articles/what-no-one-told-you-about-z-index/) More @ MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Understanding_z_index/The_stacking_context

Comment: Not sure why this post has 3 downvotes. OP explained the problem well, posted the code of his previous attempts, and clearly shows own effort. I don't think this is a bad question at all.

Answer (score 0):

What you'll need to do is also set a `z-index` on the parent `<div>`. This is because the parent `<div>` wouldn't normally overlap the other elements in the list if it doesn't have a z-index, so its children won't either. What you'll need to add to your CSS is:

```
.index_thumb:hover {
    z-index:99999; /*or some other high value*/
}
```

Then the element that is hovered over will appear on top of any other elements. You'll need to add this `z-index` to the `<div>` only when it is hovered over though, otherwise the `z-index` of the next `<div>` will be the same as the one you're hovering on, and you'll still have the exact same problem.

Comment: @user3239020 so you want to make it that when you move your mouse on top of it, the title shows up below it, and if you move your mouse off, it still shows? I'm afraid that if that's what you're trying to do, that's not possible with CSS. If that's not what you mean with this comment, please elaborate on what you meant.

Comment: I know it's not possible. I never saw that before, but it does that right now. when I remove my mouse the title stays there. weird ???

Comment: That is weird yeah. What browser are you using? I suspect it might have something to do with the `:after` pseudo-element being positioned on top of the whole page's content or something, and the `:hover` state remaining when moving off the `<div>` itself. I'd have to know what browser this goes wrong though, so I can test for solutions myself.

Comment: im using mozilla firefox

Comment: @user3239020 well the site changed, so I can't check it anymore.

Comment: @user3239020 I only just got to it checking your site, and it seems like it works fine in the most recent version of Firefox. If it doesn't for you, it's probably either because of a bug, or because you're using an outdated version of Firefox. Could you try updating your browser and seeing if it still does that?